How do I solve AxiosError: Network Error in React?
I'm a beginner and been stuck at this. Can anyone help out? Much appreciated
Network Error
AxiosError: Network Error
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50001:14)
at Axios.request (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50453:41)
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "./context/ThemeContext";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./routes/Home";
import Signin from './routes/Signin';
import Signup from './routes/Signup';
import Account from './routes/Account';
import axios from 'axios'


function App() {
  const [coins, setCoins] = useState([])

  const url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global-metrics/quotes/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=************************';

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setCoins(response.data);
      // console.log(response.data)
    });
  }, [url]);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/signin' element={<Signin />} />
        <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup />} />
        <Route path='/account' element={<Account />} />
      </Routes>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

`
If anyone has any tips would be much appreciated. Been following a tutorial and the only difference is Instead of using CoinGecko API I'm using CoinMarketCap API.
